# Protege datatype restriction

Tags: owl, protege, restriction

I have populated my ontology with data defining among others Hour. Now, I want to make a restriction on that specific datatype (hour) which is defined as int and has values from 0-23. The restriction would be set on the division of the hour according to day and night for example (hour min 6 int) and (hour max 17 int) for the day and that defined as object Property isDay, but the problem is the inferences does not happen.
Thank you in advance,
Eliot

Comment: Datatype restrictions do not apply to object properties, so that would be one issue. Another is: which reasoner are you using? Not all support user defined datatypes.

Comment: I'm not sure how it would work with an object property but if you have a class `Event` with a subclass `DayEvent`, you can define for it an equivalent class `owl:onProperty :hour; owl:someValuesFrom [
    xsd:minInclusive "6"^^xsd:int ;
    xsd:maxInclusive "17"^^xsd:int ;
    owl:onDataRange xsd:integer. ].`

Comment: @Ignazio, was this answer useful? As I referred to it from another case, please let me know if it needs to be improved.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov Looks good to me

Comment: @Ignazio since it's not accepted as an answer, I assumed I hasn't solved your problem.

Comment: I didn't ask the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `:DayEvent` class as subclass of `:Event` and then declare restriction on the dataType property `:hour` for the range you want to specify as day slot, say 6 <= DayEvent hour <=17, this way:

```
:DayEvent rdf:type owl:Class ;

      owl:equivalentClass [
                     rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                     owl:onProperty :hour ;
                     owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                                     owl:onDatatype xsd:integer ;
                                     owl:withRestrictions ( 
                                                 [ xsd:minInclusive 6]
                                                 [ xsd:maxInclusive 17]
                                                )
                                         ]
                          ] ;

      rdfs:subClassOf :Event .
```

Then all individuals with dataType property `:hour` having values within the specified range will be inferred as members of `:DayEvent`.

This would work at least with Protégé 4.3 and 5, with reasoners HermiT, FaCT++ and Pallet.

The equivalent class definition will look in Protégé syntax like this: `hour some xsd:integer[>= 6 , <= 17]` .