# create individual in protege with dataproprety restriction

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

good evening everyone
i have created a simple ontology with only one class (methods) and have dataproperty action_nb (integer) and  type witch is (String) and can only be ( choice, rank , sort ) then use a query to searche for example: 
select the method WHERE action number <20  & type = " choice"

1. how to declare the action_nb in a intervale ex: methode1 => action_nb between [10, 30].
2. how to declare the type with the three values  ex: methode1=> type:"choice";

this is the code that i have right now:

```
SELECT ?inst 
WHERE {
   ?inst ex:action_nb ?value .
   ?inst  es:type  ?typ.

    FILTER (?value < 80)
    FILTER (?typ = " tri " )
}
```

Comment: 1) The data-type restriction is explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245420/protege-datatype-restriction/36296355#36296355). 2) I would suggest declaring that as object property, and not datatype property, having a range an enumerated class allowing only the three individuals representing "choice", "rank" and "sort".

Comment: thank you sir ... 2) i think that's all i need to chose one of the three types, i declared it in the dataproprety as falow {"choix" , "rank" , "tri"} i"m having a problem now with using it in the FILTER

Comment: I have elaborated a bit more in an answer. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), you can use datatype property restrictions, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245420/protege-datatype-restriction/36296355#36296355)

For 2), you should use `owl:oneOf`. This you can do with either enumerated class or enumerated datatype:

**Enumerated Classes** can only have members within a declared list of RDF resources (individuals). You can create a different individual for each choice, and then a class `MethodType` with equivalent class the list `{choice, rank, sort}`. Please note that the curly brackets is the way it will look in Protégé. In Turtle it will look like this:

```
:MethodType
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
      rdf:type owl:Class ;
      owl:oneOf (
          :choice
          :rank
          :sort
        ) ;
    ] ;
.
```

**Enumerated Datatypes** are range restrictions consisting of lists of RDF literals, in your case the `rdfs:range` will be `owl:oneOf {"choice", "rank", "sort"}`. (Notes: 1. The comment for the curly brackets holds here was well; 2.This can also be achieved with owl:allValuesFrom restrictions.)

If the `typeOP` and `typeDP`, are espectively the object property for the first approach, and the data property for the second the queries could be:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
 ?m   a :Method;
:typeOP ?t .

FILTER EXISTS {?m :typeOP :choice}
}
```

and

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
 ?m   a :Method;
:typeDP ?t .

FILTER EXISTS {?m :typeDP "choice"}
}
```

respectively.

Comment: i used Enumerated Datatypes i declared the dataproprety of (type) in the data range expression  like this  {"choice", "rank", "sort"}. now when quering i used FILTER (?typ = " tri " ) is this true ??

Comment: You can use either `FILTER {?inst  es:type  "tri"}`, which I'd recommend in your case, or `FILTER regex(?inst, "tri")`.

Comment: i have used this query as you said:  SELECT ?inst 
WHERE {
   ?inst ex:action_nb ?value .
     FILTER (?value < 80)
    FILTER {?inst es:type "tri"}
} but it's telling me that it's  malformed query

Comment: Sorry, I omitted "EXISTS". The query should be `FILTER EXISTS {?inst es:type "tri"}`. I'll also update the answer.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, but when i use FILTER EXISTS it dose not work ... although it work fine without it. only (FILTER  (?value < 80)) ... i tried  LANGMATCHES
SAMETERM
CONTAINS  but didn't work ... do you have any idea ??!!

Comment: Which of the suggested options do you use - object property or datatype property?

Comment: i used the datatype property

Comment: Then it's either a matter of how prefixes are defined or it was to do with how SPARQL is implemented in Protégé. I had some issues with that before, so when I need to run SPARQL queries I use TopBraid. You can test you ontology by defining a test class `:Tri` equivalent to `es:type value "tri"` and then run the reasoner. If you individuals having this property are inferred as members of the class, then that part of your ontology is fine. (Note: by the way I experienced a bit different behaviour of the reasoners in Protégé 4.3, 5b17, and 5b24)